# Line 55:11: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[I want to update my state after a button clicked, below is a piece of update function handler codes where i tried to find the error and i couldn't, someone help me seems that line no.55 has an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMBNO.png)

```
const addUpdateStudentHandler =(mystudent) =>{
    axios.put(`http://localhost:3006/students/${mystudent.id}`, mystudent)
    .then(res=>{
      const{id, fullName, email} = res.data;
      console.log(res.data);
      setstudents(students.map((student) =>{
          student.id === id ? {...res.data} : student;
        })
      );
    })
  }
```

Comment: when you are using the ternary operator then you are not assigning its value to anything. It is not mandatory but acc to your code you are using `{...res.data}`, It is an object but you are not assigning it

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything here:

```
setstudents(students.map((student) =>{
          student.id === id ? {...res.data} : student;
        })
);
```

Instead, you can use an implicit return:

```
setstudents(students => students.map((student) => ({
          student.id === id ? {...res.data} : student;
        }))
);
```

Or, an explicit one:

```
setstudents(students => students.map((student) =>{
          return student.id === id ? {...res.data} : student;
        })
);
```

Comment: No problem, kindly accept this as the answer if it helped :) Happy coding!